# On an external HDD, can you make one partition booteable?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, external-hard-drive, boot-partition

i have been wondering for a good couple months now: Can you make a booteable partition on an external HDD so you don't have to use USB or CD when installing a new SO? I have a good external HDD, and i have been wondering if i can partitionate the HDD, then in that Partition make a booteable windows 7? having one partition with all my software and the other one being booteable.

Comment: Absolutely. But that doesn't necessarily mean that you can install Windows to the external drive, nor that you can boot from the drive on all systems.

Comment: I really don't want to install windows on the HDD, just simply save the USB and use only the HDD, can you tell me how to do it? i really need to know haha